# Redirecting the output of a Python script to a file

Tags: python

The python script is supposed to print some messages and also compile a code multiple times for different cases. The compilation process itself generates messages on the screen for each case. I intend to have the output of the script messages and the compilation process messages all displayed out as well written out in a log file so that I can look into just one file for any issues.

I have tried having these lines:

```
import sys

class Logger(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open("regress.log", "a")

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)

sys.stdout = Logger()
```

Problem with the this:
This only prints the messages from the original python script but the compilation messages from the code that I try to compile from inside the scripts are not written in the file.

I have also tried simply : 
python script.py > output

Problem with that: 
The output file only consists of the compilation messages from the code within are written in "output" file. The messages from the script are not printed. Also, the compilation messages are not displayed on screen as well.

Essentially, I want to get all the normal print and the output of launched commands written in one single file and displayed on screen as well.

Comment: Please add more detail, including what you have tried already. Refer to the site [FAQ for how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking); specifically ["How to ask a good question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it is written, this question will likely be put on hold.

Comment: Using external redirection you could python script.py > output 2>&1 or python script.py > output  2> erroroutput

Comment: This does not output anything on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it from command line:

```
python script_name.py > output_name
```

Comment: This looks like homework, and the OP doesn't appear to have given any effort into solving or. We shouldn't encourage such questions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, all it requires you to do is;

```
def log_msg(msg):
    log = open("C:/Path/to/File.log", "a")
    log.write(msg+"\n")
    log.close()

print "Error message"
log_msg("Error Message")
```

~~~~

**Next time, please remember to post what you have tried, what you will think will work, and what didn't work, as well as some of your code.**

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do something like this is to work with the standard logging system.

You'll need to append 2 handlers a StreamHandler for sys.stdout and a FileHandler for to store the content in disk.

Check this for more information:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html